# How to find exact implementation of __builtin_popcountll?

Tags: c++, simd, icc

The gcc compiler is old (4.1.2). I installed the 2016 version of intel c compiler (icc). I am compiling a program that uses "__builtin_popcountll" by the icc.

From the discussion at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36041
We get faster implementation of builtin_popcountll in later version of gcc. I want to know if these faster implementations are used.

How to find out the exact implementation of "__builtin_popcountll" that is used?

I can't use SSE 4.2's popcnt instruction. The cpu only support sse 4.1.

output of cat /proc/cpuinfo:

```
processor   : 7
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5420  @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 10
cpu MHz     : 2493.752
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx lm constant_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 cx16 xtpr lahf_lm
bogomips    : 4987.85
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 38 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

Thank you.

Update:

asm output from icc

```
# mark_description "Intel(R) C Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 16.0.3.210 Build 20160415";
# mark_description "-S -fsource-asm -c";
    .file "small.cpp"
    .text
..TXTST0:
# -- Begin  main
    .text
# mark_begin;
       .align    16,0x90
    .globl main
# --- main()
main:
..B1.1:                         # Preds ..B1.0

### void main(void){

    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
..___tag_value_main.1:
..L2:
                                                          #9.16
        pushq     %rbp                                          #9.16
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movq      %rsp, %rbp                                    #9.16
    .cfi_def_cfa 6, 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
        andq      $-128, %rsp                                   #9.16
        subq      $128, %rsp                                    #9.16
        xorl      %esi, %esi                                    #9.16
        movl      $3, %edi                                      #9.16
        call      __intel_new_feature_proc_init                 #9.16
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15
..B1.4:                         # Preds ..B1.1
        stmxcsr   (%rsp)                                        #9.16

###     int i = 1;
###     test(i);
### }

        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #12.1
        orl       $32832, (%rsp)                                #9.16
        ldmxcsr   (%rsp)                                        #9.16
        movq      %rbp, %rsp                                    #12.1
        popq      %rbp                                          #12.1
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    .cfi_restore 6
        ret                                                     #12.1
        .align    16,0x90
    .cfi_endproc
                                # LOE
# mark_end;
    .type   main,@function
    .size   main,.-main
    .data
# -- End  main
    .text
# -- Begin  _Z4testi
    .text
# mark_begin;
       .align    16,0x90
    .globl _Z4testi
# --- test(int)
_Z4testi:
# parameter 1: %edi
..B2.1:                         # Preds ..B2.0

### int test(int i){

    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
..___tag_value__Z4testi.9:
..L10:
                                                         #6.16

###       return __builtin_popcountll(i); //somehow it says _mm_popcnt_u32 is illegal instruction 

        movq      $0x5555555555555555, %rax                     #7.14
        movslq    %edi, %rdi                                    #7.14
        movq      $0x3333333333333333, %rcx                     #7.14
        movq      %rdi, %rdx                                    #7.14
        movq      $0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f, %r8                       #7.14
        shrq      $1, %rdx                                      #7.14
        movq      $0x101010101010101, %r9                       #7.14
        andq      %rax, %rdx                                    #7.14
        subq      %rdx, %rdi                                    #7.14
        movq      %rdi, %rax                                    #7.14
        andq      %rcx, %rdi                                    #7.14
        shrq      $2, %rax                                      #7.14
        andq      %rcx, %rax                                    #7.14
        addq      %rdi, %rax                                    #7.14
        movq      %rax, %rsi                                    #7.14
        shrq      $4, %rsi                                      #7.14
        addq      %rsi, %rax                                    #7.14
        andq      %r8, %rax                                     #7.14
        imulq     %r9, %rax                                     #7.14
        shrq      $56, %rax                                     #7.14
        ret                                                     #7.14
        .align    16,0x90
    .cfi_endproc
                                # LOE
# mark_end;
    .type   _Z4testi,@function
    .size   _Z4testi,.-_Z4testi
    .data
# -- End  _Z4testi
    .data
    .section .note.GNU-stack, ""
// -- Begin DWARF2 SEGMENT .eh_frame
    .section .eh_frame,"a",@progbits
.eh_frame_seg:
    .align 8
# End
```

gcc godbolt of x86 icc 13.0.1

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
int square(int num) {
  return __builtin_popcountll(num);
}

L__routine_start__Z6squarei_0:
square(int):
        pushq     %rbp                                          #2.21
        movq      %rsp, %rbp                                    #2.21
        subq      $16, %rsp                                     #2.21
        movl      %edi, -8(%rbp)                                #2.21
        movl      -8(%rbp), %eax                                #3.10
        movslq    %eax, %rax                                    #3.10
        movq      %rax, %rdx                                    #3.10
        shrq      $1, %rdx                                      #3.10
        movq      $0x5555555555555555, %rcx                     #3.10
        andq      %rcx, %rdx                                    #3.10
        subq      %rdx, %rax                                    #3.10
        movq      %rax, %rdx                                    #3.10
        shrq      $2, %rdx                                      #3.10
        movq      $0x3333333333333333, %rcx                     #3.10
        andq      %rcx, %rdx                                    #3.10
        andq      %rcx, %rax                                    #3.10
        addq      %rax, %rdx                                    #3.10
        movq      %rdx, %rax                                    #3.10
        shrq      $4, %rax                                      #3.10
        addq      %rax, %rdx                                    #3.10
        movq      $0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f, %rax                      #3.10
        andq      %rax, %rdx                                    #3.10
        movq      %rdx, %rax                                    #3.10
        shrq      $8, %rax                                      #3.10
        addq      %rax, %rdx                                    #3.10
        movq      %rdx, %rax                                    #3.10
        shrq      $16, %rax                                     #3.10
        addq      %rax, %rdx                                    #3.10
        movq      %rdx, %rax                                    #3.10
        shrq      $32, %rax                                     #3.10
        addq      %rax, %rdx                                    #3.10
        andq      $255, %rdx                                    #3.10
        movl      %edx, -16(%rbp)                               #3.10
        movl      -16(%rbp), %eax                               #3.10
        leave                                                   #3.10
        ret                                                     #3.10
```

gcc godbolt of x86 gcc 6

```
square(int):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        cltq
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    __popcountdi2
        leave
        ret
```

Can't see what is the __popcountdi2. But I guess I will just test the speed of the build in implementation and the one in gcc.gnu.org and see which one is faster.

Comment: compile to a cpu that supports the instruction. check the generated asm.

Comment: http://gcc.godbolt.org/  Write a function that takes an arg and returns a value.

Comment: but... is that same as the ancient gcc on the computer. Or the strange combination of new icc and the old standard library? The program is just for that system. I will try gcc 4.1.2 there anyway.

Comment: Ok fine, then do the same thing on your own system if the selection of compilers on godbolt doesn't include what you want to test.  godbolt doesn't change the asm output, just removes clutter other than labels and instructions for you.

Comment: Also note that `popcnt` isn't part of SSE4.2.  Intel added both in Nehalem, but they have separate feature bits, and you need to use `-mpopcnt` to enable it.  (`_mm_popcnt_u32` is the intrinsic for the popcnt instruction.  Unlike the GNU C builtin, it doesn't have any kind of fallback for targets that don't support the instruction).

Comment: I got the command for icc now. Thanks for the suggestions.  "icc -mmic -S -fsource-asm -c foo.c" I also found that godbolt can generate asm with an old version of icc.